# Convert RGB Color in SVG to Spot Color in PDF

Tags: svg, ghostscript, icc, spotcolor

we are building an web application to design print products online. There are also some special finishes available for print. For example gold foil. There for we have to define the color in the final PDF in a specific way. It has to be a spot color with 100% magenta (c0 m100 y0 k0) and th color name "goldfoil".

In the design tool we are using a color with a hex code that is looking similar to gold in the browser (#9C9475). Our application is creating SVG that is converted via ghostscript to the PDF.

What I now want to achieve is to define a fallback or exchange color for specific hex colors like in this example #9C9475 that will convert this color in the PDF to the above described spot color.

Will this be possible? I found an article that svg 1.1 and above is supporting ICC Profiles and can produce CMYK and ICC named colors. In the documentation it says that I can define spot color in this way:

```
<color-profile name=„ISOcoated_v2_eci" xlink:href="http://swatches.example.com/ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc"/>
 <circle fill=„#9C9475 icc-color(ISOcoated_v2_eci, Goldfolie"/>
```

But then I am missing the CMYK values.

Can somebody help me in this case?

Comment: There's no reason why you would necessarily get CMYK colours, the alternate might be defined as RGB. What **do** you get out ? I'm unclear on ho wyou are using Ghostscript to convert an SVG to PDF, since Ghostscript doesn't read SVG files....

Comment: Hi Ken,
sorry for the delay. We still are searching for a solution. What we now do is to convert svg file via inkscape command prompt to rgb pdf. This pdf is converted via ghostscript to cmyk. We are now looking for a way to replace rgb/hex color to spot color....

Comment: Well basically you can't reliably do that (from a PDF file). Its entirely possible that any given PDF file will contain an RGB triplet which has the value 0x9c9475. If you go around replacing all the drawing operations with that spcific colour then you may well turn something that **shouldn't** be a separation colour into a separation colour. I can't comment on SVG and ICC named colours, I don't know enough about it. You could hack Ghostscript's pdfwrite device to spot linework RGB values and create a Separation space instead, but that would be really quite hard to do.